# Limiting area codes in phone number entered

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char text[81];
    cout << "Enter phone number:";
    cin.getline(text, 81);

    char numbers[15] = { " 0123456789()-" };

    int size_of = strlen(text);


    int counter = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a<size_of; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b<14; b++)
        {
            if (text[a] == numbers[b])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (counter == size_of)
    {
        cout << "Phone number is valid";
        return 0;
    }

    else
        cout << "Phone number is invalid";
        return -1;

    int stop;
    cin >> stop;


}
```

There is no problem with the code itself, but i'm just stuck on how I can limit the valid phone numbers to a certain set of area codes. For example only the area codes 555 246 and 131 are allowed.

Comment: They added regular expressions in C++11, why not just use that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like setting up three char values to hold the valid area codes 555, 246, and 131. Then for each number phone number entered compare the valid area codes with the first three numbers of the entered phone number.